# Emitir um ALERT para um campo UNIQUE no Mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, alert

Tenho um campo no BD setado como Unique, para evitar a duplicidade no cadastro. Funciona perfeitamente. Gostaria de saber se há como personalizar essa mensagem, com um Alert, por exemplo.

Meu código:

```
<?php

require 'conexao.php';

$nome               =           addslashes ($_POST['nome']);
$foto1              =           addslashes ($_POST['foto1']);
$cpf                =           addslashes ($_POST['cpf']);
$rg                 =           addslashes ($_POST['rg']);
$email              =           addslashes ($_POST['email']);
$telefone           =           addslashes ($_POST['telefone']);
$endereco           =           addslashes ($_POST['endereco']);
$bairro             =           addslashes ($_POST['bairro']);
$cidade             =           addslashes ($_POST['cidade']);
$estado             =           addslashes ($_POST['estado']);
$observacoes        =           addslashes ($_POST['observacoes']);
$curso              =           addslashes ($_POST['curso']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO cursoest set nome = :nome, foto1 = :foto1, cpf = :cpf, rg = :rg, email = :email, telefone = :telefone, endereco = :endereco, bairro = :bairro, cidade = :cidade, estado = :estado, observacoes = :observacoes, curso = :curso";

$stmt = $PDO->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindParam( ':nome', $nome );
$stmt->bindParam( ':foto1', $foto1 );
$stmt->bindParam( ':cpf', $cpf );
$stmt->bindParam( ':rg', $rg );
$stmt->bindParam( ':email', $email );
$stmt->bindParam( ':telefone', $telefone );
$stmt->bindParam( ':endereco', $endereco );
$stmt->bindParam( ':bairro', $bairro );
$stmt->bindParam( ':cidade', $cidade );
$stmt->bindParam( ':estado', $estado );
$stmt->bindParam( ':observacoes', $observacoes );
$stmt->bindParam( ':curso', $curso );
$result = $stmt->execute();

if ( ! $result )
    {
var_dump( $stmt->errorInfo() );
exit;
    }
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Matrícula realizada com sucesso!");</script>';
echo "<script>window.location = 'matriculaok.html';</script>";
//echo $stmt->rowCount() . "Matrícula realizada com sucesso!";

?>
```

Pelo que pesquisei, poderia colocar um `PDO:errorInfo`? Como fazer?

Comment: Tira aquele `var_dump()` verifique o código do erro é `1062` e exiba a mensagem referente do contrário diga que teve um erro ... algo como "entre em contato com o administrador" não esqueça de logar esse erro.

Comment: Fiz algo aqui apressado, acabou tendo o resultado que eu esperava... Mas não deve ser da forma mais correta. Gostaria que me explicasse melhor ou desse referências, para que eu possa corrigir ou aplicar em outro projeto, por favor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi assim:

```
<?php

require 'conexao.php';

$nome               =           addslashes ($_POST['nome']);
$foto1              =           addslashes ($_POST['foto1']);
$cpf                =           addslashes ($_POST['cpf']);
$rg                 =           addslashes ($_POST['rg']);
$email              =           addslashes ($_POST['email']);
$telefone           =           addslashes ($_POST['telefone']);
$endereco           =           addslashes ($_POST['endereco']);
$bairro             =           addslashes ($_POST['bairro']);
$cidade             =           addslashes ($_POST['cidade']);
$estado             =           addslashes ($_POST['estado']);
$observacoes        =           addslashes ($_POST['observacoes']);
$curso              =           addslashes ($_POST['curso']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO cursoest set nome = :nome, foto1 = :foto1, cpf = :cpf, rg = :rg, email = :email, telefone = :telefone, endereco = :endereco, bairro = :bairro, cidade = :cidade, estado = :estado, observacoes = :observacoes, curso = :curso";

$stmt = $PDO->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindParam( ':nome', $nome );
$stmt->bindParam( ':foto1', $foto1 );
$stmt->bindParam( ':cpf', $cpf );
$stmt->bindParam( ':rg', $rg );
$stmt->bindParam( ':email', $email );
$stmt->bindParam( ':telefone', $telefone );
$stmt->bindParam( ':endereco', $endereco );
$stmt->bindParam( ':bairro', $bairro );
$stmt->bindParam( ':cidade', $cidade );
$stmt->bindParam( ':estado', $estado );
$stmt->bindParam( ':observacoes', $observacoes );
$stmt->bindParam( ':curso', $curso );
$result = $stmt->execute();

if ( ! $result )
    {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("CPF já cadastrado em nosso Banco de Dados!");</script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.history.back(-1);</script>';
exit;
    }

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Matrícula realizada com sucesso!");</script>';
echo "<script>window.location = 'matriculaok.html';</script>";
//echo $stmt->rowCount() . "Matrícula realizada com sucesso!";

?>
```

Comment: A intenção é boa, mas como você garante que o valor de `$result` realmente ficou falso por causa de um valor repetido e não por causa de qualquer outro problema? I.e.: falha de referência, problema de conexão etc.

Comment: Tem razão, meu amigo. Como expliquei acima, fiz pra "grego" ver, para não perder o contrato... rs... se tiver uma sugestão para pesquisa, serei eternamente grato.